# Exporting stock chart (ohlc) to Excel by C# code

Tags: .net, excel, epplus, aspose, candlestick-chart

I want to export the stock chart ohlc to Excel

I'm using EPPlus, now I came to know that EPPlus does not support stock charts to draw, hence I'm looking for another third party dll, I've found aspose, but it's paid kind of feature to use.

Can anyone suggest any other for exporting stock chart creating stock chart in Excel by C# code?

Or is it possible to create stock chart ohlc in Excel by C# by EPPlus?

When using the aspose, I need to use it in bw the code, wen I save the aspose workbook, it pops exception that file is being used by another process, is there any way to forcefully close the process accessing it, or making it to be over written by it?

Adding to above, I've got EPPlus and also the aspose at a same tym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create Stock chart using Aspose.Cells. The following stock charts are supported in Aspose.Cells:

- High-low-close stock chart
- Open-high-low-close stock chart
- Volume-high-low-close stock chart
- Volume-open-high-low-close stock chart

For your issue regarding the file is being used by another process, such issue occurs, when you for example try to save your workbook as c:\output.xlsx and at the same time, you have opened it in Microsoft Excel.

In this case, Aspose.Cells will not be able to save to c:\output.xlsx because c:\output.xlsx is being used by another process i.e Microsoft Excel. You should first close c:\output.xlsx in Microsoft Excel, then Aspose.Cells will be able to save it to c:\output.xlsx.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: I've used ASPOSE, its a sign of gud work. But, limitation still exists as stock chart with huge data with show line/bar chart as ant moving in structure. Can Aspose develop charts with scroll/scale feature?

Comment: Most of the charts and chart features are supported by Aspose.Cells. Please get the help related to this on Aspose.Cells forum. You need to provide us your sample excel chart which you can create manually using Microsoft Excel. We will then investigate it and provide you a sample code to achieve the same chart programmatically using Aspose.Cells APIs. Kindly post your issue in Aspose.Cells forum in this regard. ( http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx )